# Regex to check character password repeat frequency

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a password rules to follow:

[image: printscreen of the rules]

Disregard the 90 days part.

This is what I already have:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{7,}$
```

What is and how can I add the password repeat frequency regex block???

Comment: What do you mean by repeat frequency?

Comment: "Repeat frequency" seems to refer to how many passwords a user can employ before being able to repeat the first one, as "repeating ***characters***" are a separate option at the bottom of the Required Password Characters optionset.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check a password repeat frequency with a regular expression. The password repeat frequency usually constrains how soon you are allowed to reuse a password. A regex can't check for old passwords.